# How to run objective c simple program in windows

Tags: objective-c

I just started my "Hello World" program in objective C on windows.I have installed all related software from "gnusetp.org" website. I make one hello world program and save it in "c:\hello.m" directory. I want to know how will i compile it ? wen i am running command prompt with gnsetup executable file i m seeing "sh.exe-41.$". What i have to do next to compile and run well ?
Thanks

Comment: Hi,, This is now running..simple thingie with commands  No help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the gnustep prompt, cd to C:\ and try this (note: this is just one line):

> gcc -o hello.exe hello.m -std=c99 
>   -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers 
>   -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries 
>   -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -fobjc-exceptions